# Worklight - using the WL libraries in an iframe

Tags: javascript, caching, ibm-mobilefirst, encryption

So I think the general advice for using iframes in an application is a no as far as Worklight goes (and probably in general app development contexts too). Unfortunately, I don't have a choice but to use iframes for this particular task (it's not my decision and I won't bore you with the details!) and part of the application requires the encrypted cache to be used on the iframe which is essentially a form with data entry (this data entry is what I want to encrypt).

Now, when I do this, I of course get the WL is not defined error. I've tried to include the necessary JS files to initiate the WL library, but I guess as it's already defined within the context of the active application in the background of this iframe, it won't work. Can anybody help with this? I'm not sure how else to make use of the encrypted cache without re-loading the WL libraries, but this isn't straight forward, unless I missed a trick.

Any ideas welcomed, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use JSONStore instead, then?

- IBM Worklight Getting Started: [Advanced client-side development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development)
- IBM Worklight Information Center: [JSONStore Overview](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html)

Although they may be the same problem, as you are using an iFrame. Don't use iFrames!

Comment: As I understand it, this relies upon having an external WL server to make use of the JSONStore, doesn't it? This development is on my local machine, so I don't think this would solve my problem - unless my understanding is incorrect. I guess your reply confirms that I can't use the WL libraries in an iframe?

Comment: And even if my understanding is incorrect, to make calls to that (to add to your JSON store, read from it etc.) you still have to use WL.callhere, hence a dependency on the WL libraries which is my initial problem.

Comment: Some JSONStore functionality relies on server connectivity, you do not have to use this functionality. Is this data of the iFrame coming from remote location or local? And yes, on second thought you may encounter the same issue. I suggest that you explain the need for an iFrame even though you think you will bore us with it, because this is crucial.

Comment: Okay, so the iframe is showing a form which is retrieved from an external location in the background, taking the html retrieved, and populating the form locally (so the iframe is actually a local web page). If there's no way around the WL library issue then I guess I'll have to convince the guys to not use iframes, although I think the form renders incorrectly if just placed in a div.

Comment: I highly doubt you will want or can make it easy to "load" Worklight externally to the application. Suggest them to not use iFrames.

Comment: I'll find a workaround, I've accepted your answer below as I agree, iframes aren't the answer! Thanks.